# Make the user's viewport scroll up upon clicking a certain css class or ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

(for reference I am using DIVI for Wordpress, trying to accomplish this with a code block)

I have a slider/carousel with 7 steps that all have "next" and "previous" buttons for the user to go through. When a user clicks next onto step 2, because the step 1 window is larger than step 2, it means their window is now below step 2 (the "next" and "previous" buttons are at the bottom of each slider).

The buttons currently use a # link to open the next slider which works well, but I need a function that makes it so when one of the links (all have the class ".rv-welcome-stagebutton") is clicked, it moves the window back up to the top of the carousel.

So the user doesn't have to constantly scroll back to the top of each stage.

I have tried using the current code on the page but no luck.

TLDR: what I'm trying to achieve -

- User clicks a link with css class ".rv-welcome-stagebutton"
- scroll the window up to the top of the section with ID "#rv-welcomeslider-container"

[GIF OF PAGE IN ACTION: [https://i.imgur.com/fQiFjnK.gif]](https://i.imgur.com/fQiFjnK.gif)

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">                              
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.rv-welcome-stagebutton').click(function(){
  window.scroll({
  top: 0, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});}   }                   

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : I made few mistakes in my last response, I fixed it now, try it.

I think I can fix this for you. You already use jQuery, so that's great.

First, we gotta see what is a distance between top of the page, and top part of your section (#rv-welcomeslider-container).

We can do this with jQuery `offset().top` which will return how much is your section far from the top of the document.

So, we write : `let getSectionCoords = $("#rv-welcomeslider-container").offset().top;`

Now all we have to do is add a `click` event to every button (.rv-welcome-stagebutton), and make it scroll right to the top of your carousel section (which is getSectionCoords now).

So, here is the final code :

```
let getSectionCoords = $("#rv-welcomeslider-container").offset().top;

$('.rv-welcome-stagebutton').on('click',function() {

    $('body').animate({scrollTop : getHeadingThree}, '500');

});
```

Let me know if it worked :)